# Tips for integrating on a symmetric domain?

Tags: integration

One of the problems of my homework consists in integrating $\iint_D(x^2y^2+sin(xy)e^{{x^2}y^2})dA$ on the quadrilateral domain $D$ formed by (1,0), (0,2), (-1,0) and (0,-2). This domain is symmetric on both oX and oY axes. We've been told to use the parity of the functions to manage to integrate. Problem is that I believe variables must be first separated or a first integration must be done to apply any theorem. Could anyone please give me a clue as to how to start with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider integration through the two triangles you obtain by cutting through the $x$-axis. Cancellation will happen by symmetry in the $y$ variable, to leave you with an easy double integral of the $x^2y^2$ part. You need to use that $\sin (-t)=-\sin t$.

**ADD** More formally, let $R_1$ be the region determined by the triangle with vertices $(-1,0),(1,0),(,2)$ and let $R_2$ be the region determined by the triangle with vertices $(-1,0),(1,0),(0,-2)$.

The linear transformation $T(x,y)=(x,-y)$ is an isometry, hence has $|J_T(x,y)|=1$, that mapsto $R_1$ to $R_2$, and if $f(x,y)=x^2y^2+\sin(xy)e^{x^2y^2}$ then $$f\circ T(x,y)|J_T(x,y)|+f(x,y)=f(x,-y)+f(x,y)=2x^2y^2$$

Now integrate over $R_2$, to obtain that $$\int_{R_2} f\circ T \;\;|J_T|+\int_{R_2}f=2\int_{R_2}x^2y^2\\ \int_{R_1} f+\int_{R_2}f=2\int_{R_2}x^2y^2\\ \int_Df=2\int_{R_2}x^2y^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that $sin$ is an odd function and that the second part of the integral should be ruled out, but I don't know how to reach that conclusion. We've only had an example in class where variables were separated and the conclusion I came to is that "if the function is odd with respect to X and the domain symmetric with respect to oY, the integral of the function is 0", vice-versa for the second variable. I just don't know how to apply this in this specific case, since we got two variables in the same terms. Thank !

Comment: @BobLeponge Maybe the add helps.